# Что вы можете посоветовать новичку?

Tags: java, c++

Что мне сначала учить Java или C++?

Comment: Python.

Comment: Сложно сказать. И C++ и Java на данный момент очень широко везде используются. Так что по большей части - выбирайте то, что больше понравится, тем более, что при необходимости довольно легко можно перейти с одного на другой.

Comment: Лично я бы посоветовал новичку в первую очередь изучить C - простой язык, но дает общее понимание процессов происходящих на низком уровне. А затем уже переходить на высокоуровневые языки, тут особо нет разницы C++, Java или C#

Comment: Имхо проще начать с java, освоив основы ООП, вы поймете, как не надо писать плохой код на процедурном языке (начальный уровень С именно такой). Изучая С, вы научитесь не злоупотреблять ООП на Java.

Comment: Поставьте себе задачу, исходя из задачи станет ясно, какими средствами её удобнее решать.

Comment: Очень важно также знать английский язык. Очень сильно пригодится.

Comment: > освоив основы ООП вы поймете как ненадо писать говнокод на процедурном языке

Не согласен. В первую очередь нужно понять алгоритмизацию. А мишура вроде ООП этому мешает. А затем уже можно переходить на ООП парадигму. При этом очень пригодится навык декомпозиции задачи, полученный на процедурном уровне. А еще лучше - освоить функциональное программирование. Оно очень хорошо вправляет мозги на место и позволяет понять, как например, строить крупные системы с параллелизацией (вот где пригодится знание о побочных эффектах выполнения кода!)

Comment: И я с вами не согласен, т.к. вы смотрите с идеальной точки зрения, когда человек знает, кем он хочет быть через 10 лет. И знает какие технологии ему учить. А я отношусь к категории людей, которые ничего не будут учить, пока не отвечу для себя на вопрос: "Я это выучу, потому что мне надо для... ". Типичная проблема нашей системы образования, когда студентов заставляют что-то учить, но непонятно, зачем им это.

Comment: продолжение: получив минимальный набор знаний ООП (т.е. научившись хоть что-то писать чтоб душа порадовалась) можно приступать к более серьезным вещам, типа алгоритмизации. потому что следующим шагом может стать сравнение алгоритмов и их эффективности (что даст человеку очень полезные знания + мотивацию для продолжения учебы).

представляюю шок новичка когда его не окрепший програмерский моск будет читать умные толстые книжки (а ведь еще нет уверенного знания языка это + еще 1-2 толстые книжки)

Answer (score 2):

Все сильно зависит от того, какие программы Вы хотите писать. Если это интернет приложения - почти однозначно Java. Если высокопроизводительные клиентские или драйвера - то С++. Каждый язык хорош для определенной задачи.
При этом от себя лично добавлю, что в качестве учебного языка Java лучше, так как имеет более строгую типизацию и позволяет на начальном этапе не забивать голову системными вещами. Но, в то же время, это же в нем и плохо - если потом жизнь столкнет с С++, то будет крайне трудно ко всему этому привыкать.

Comment: главное не начинать с php и python( его лучше изучать имхо после c++ and java) иначе вообще потом аццки сложно будет

Comment: Драйвера на С++? Перебор это. Драйвера пишутся практически на голом  С. Высокоэффективный код на С++? Согласен, но это сложно. Лучше изучить какой-нить функциональный язык или тот же python.

Answer (score 1):

При знании С вы сможете даже не выбирать, какой из них сначала учить.
Но если знания по С отсутствуют, то лучше, по-моему, С++, ибо без знания указателей (без понимания, как это все работает) довольно сложно писать быстрые программы на обоих языках.

Comment: Указатели стоит знать хотя бы для того, чтобы осознавать опасность их использования и стараться избегать их (в java их нет, в С++ часто рекомендуют придерживаться RAII).
"Преждевременная оптимизация — это корень всех бед".

Comment: Указатели стоит знать хотя бы для того, чтобы осознавать, как все на самом деле устроено.

Comment: http://russian.joelonsoftware.com/Articles/BacktoBasics.html.
Да и RAII не везде применишь.

Comment: Про то и речь. Тот же `strcat()` был бы намного проще, если бы изначально использовались подобающие строки (например, содержащие длину, вроде .net-овских, либо BSTR).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы планируете изучать оба языка, то лучше сначала учить С++, ибо после него Java понять куда проще, в отличие от обратной ситуации.

Comment: Но после хорошего уровня в с++, от java почему-то воротит, :) то GC шалит и настраивают, то typedef нет.

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от того, в какой области вы хотите работать. Что вам больше интересно. От этого и надо плясать дальше. Почитайте и позадавайте вопросы в инете, где какой язык применяется, хотя это можно выяснить, не задавая вопросы, и понять, что Вам ближе, что Вам интереснее. Главное понимать, что C++ и Java - не одно и тоже и разница есть и причём немалая, что изучать.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того чего вы хотите.

Java это всего лишь обрубок C++. Выучив C++ вам придется немного прочитать о Java и вы сможете спокойно писать на обоих языках.

Если вы хотите сразу писать кросс платформенные приложения и не собираетесь учить другие языки - займитесь Java.

Я бы рекомендовал начать с C++.

Comment: "Java это всего лишь обрубок C++." - ??? Не могу придумать, за что можно так Java назвать. Java не является подмножеством C++. В чём обрубленность заключается?
Можно и на C++ писать кроссплатформенные приложения. Вы имели в виду "один раз скомпилировал - запускай, где хочешь".

Comment: Я имел ввиду Java была создана после C++ и является его потомком. Есть вещи которые можно сделать на C++ но нельзя на Java. Именно поэтому Java всего лишь обрубок. Это совершенно не значит что она чем то хуже (как язык).

Comment: Однако существуют задачи, которые сложно решить на C++, однако легко на Java, например, сериализация графа объектов.

Answer (score 0):

Я начал с C++ - им доволен. Многое зависит от учебника. Оба языка функциональны, но в Java в основном ООП, тогда как в C++ можно одинаково хорошо писать и на ООП и процедурно (имхо).
Я пытался сначала разобраться в веб-программировании, но хорошего учебника не нашел, а на C++ нашел.