# Следующий шаг после книг

Tags: java

> Сделан вопросом из ответа в теме "[Что вы можете посоветовать новичку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/27350/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83)" @Хэшкод

Когда книги рекомендуемые прочитаны, на чем лучше тренироваться? Какие проекты сейчас в силе, очень хочется знать. Плиз.

Comment: это ответ или вопрос? похоже вопрос - так и задавайте как вопрос.

Comment: Это вопрос. Как подготовиться к реальным проектам, одновременно изучая Java?

Comment: Hello world уже написаны, упражнения по книге сделаны и осознаны. А дальше?

Answer (score 12):

Ищем первого заказчика.

- Оптимально, если это будет кто-то знакомый и с большим терпением).
- Можно даже "забесплатно" или за символическую цену.
- Естественно не оговариваем сроки.
- Естественно не беремся делать космос.
- Ищем хороший источник (сайт, книгу...) исходников, чтоб можно было консультироваться.
- Запасаемся валерьянкой и/или вазелином.

Начинаем)

Вопрос - что именно писать - не стоит. "Проекты в силе" - не факт что потяните (я естественно не в коей мере не пытаюсь занизить вашу самооценку). 
Важно "въехать" в струю понять как это делается.

Следующим шагом можно искать комманду, которая работает в близком направлении и учится дальше с ними. А там вы сами поймете интересно ли вам, что именно интересно, кем можете ли быть в комманде, или может вообще поймете, что для вас это "тесно".

Comment: Золотые твои слова, Юрий Венедиктович!(С)

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно посоветовать поискать работу "практикантом". Пусть будет минимальный оклад, зато будете вертеться среди программистов и постепенно вольетесь в струю.
Единственный минус - могут быть трудности при поиске такой работы, ведь практикантики почти никому не нужны...

Answer (score 1):

я бы вам посоветовал сделать какой-нибудь сайт. даже если он никуда дальше не двинется, кроме как локально будет запускаться на вашей машине, это будет не плохой опыт. конечно я думаю стоит использовать фреимворки, например Spring, Spring MVC, Freemarker/Velocity, Hibernate. и использовать сборщик проектов(например maven). ну и систему контроля версий заюзать(например subversion). всё это используется на реальных проектах, поэтому попробуйте подготовится.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовала сделать сайт себе, тем более, что рано и поздно он вам все равно понадобится.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовала Вам тренироваться не после прочтения литературы, а непосредственно в момент изучения теории